# how to get all connected users in websocket using simplebroker or rabbitMQ with java spring

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

how to get all connected users in websocket chat app using simplebroker or rabbitMQ with java spring

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpUserRegistry;

```
@Autowired
SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;
...
public void foo(){
    simpUserRegistry.getUsers();
}
```